# Missing quick launch on workflow initiation form

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, workflow, quick-launch

After creating a workflow in SharePoint Foundation 2010, the workflow initiation form is always missing the quick launch bar on the left side. There is only an empty div in the page source code visible:

```
<div id="s4-leftpanel-content"></div>
```

Is there any way to add the quick launch bar manually to an existing workflow initation form?